# Align input controls in zurb foundation in same row

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am beginner of zurb foundation and trying to use zurb foundation with asp.net forms 4.0 for a simple forms.

I have fixed my row with at `768px' as this is a requirement.

my structure is like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-11 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME:">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">*</div>
</div>
```

I am using this structure so that i validation fails * show next to input box. This works fine on desktop. But when i test it for screen width 768pxels   then `<div class="large-11 columns">` take all the space and validation moves down to next line.

Is their a ways i can prevent it so that it will give both columns in same row.

I am not sure how to do this in zurb.

Fiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/8ww2v/7/

Answer (score 0):

In order to target all devices, add a class of small, medium and large:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ww2v/9/)

```
   <div class="row">
                <div class="small-11 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME:" />
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-11 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME:" />
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-11 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL:" />
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-11 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                    <textarea placeholder="ADDRESS"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
            </div>
```

To target only tablets and desktop:

Since 768px is for tablets you will add a class of medium.

Try this:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ww2v/8/)

```
        <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-11 large-11 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME:"/>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-11 large-11 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME:"/>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-11 large-11 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL:"/>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-11 large-11 columns">  
        <textarea placeholder="ADDRESS"></textarea>
        </div>
    <div class="medium-1 large-1 columns">*</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not only for tablets, i have to target all devices mobile as well as desktop. I tried your option it breaks and moves the validation `*` to next line..

Comment: Add a class of small, medium and large to target all devices.
See my updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Foundation is a mobile-first framework, every size will be valid for greatest, so there's no need to use something like `small-11 medium-11 large-11`, use just `small-11` and will work (unless you want different sizing, then you'll put the class)